# Primefaces Nested dataTable's columnToggler does not show colums

Tags: primefaces, datatable, nested

Im using primefaces 5.3. I have dataTable nested in two accordionPanel.
Below code working good but columnTogler shows columns only for active accordion tab. Other datatable's columnTogler dont show columns. Only white square appaers.
If i change tabs activeIndex property, columnTogler works for only that active tab, no others.

Here is my Xhtml:

```
<p:accordionPanel value="#{nestedtablebn.lessonList}" var="lesson" >
                    <p:tab title="#{lesson.name}"  titleStyleClass="firstAcc">
                        <p:accordionPanel value="#{lesson.studentList}" var="student" activeIndex="none">
                            <p:tab title="#{student.name}" titleStyleClass="innerAcc" >

                                <h:inputHidden value="#{student.id}" id="hiddenId"></h:inputHidden>

                                <p:dataTable value="#{student.bookList}"  var="book" id="book" paginator="true" >
                                    <f:facet name="header">                        
                                        <p:commandButton id="toggler" type="link" value="Kolonlar" style="float:right; font-size:12px; margin-top: 10px;"  />
                                        <p:columnToggler datasource="book" trigger="toggler" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <p:column headerText="No" style="width:20px !important;">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{book.id}"></h:outputText>
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Kitap Adı">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{book.name}"></h:outputText>
                                    </p:column>
                                </p:dataTable>
                                <h:commandLink id="excel">
                                    <p:graphicImage name="img/excel.png" />
                                    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="book" fileName="Report" />
                                </h:commandLink>
                            </p:tab>
                        </p:accordionPanel>


                    </p:tab>
                </p:accordionPanel>
```

Comment: Tried 6.0? 6.1-Snapshot?

Comment: Yes i have. At PF 6.0, even white square dont appears.